# Html.Action with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, attributerouting

My route attribute is like below

```
   [RouteArea("Settings")]
   [RoutePrefix("Stores")]
 public class SettingsMallStoresController : Controller
    {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ExistingStores/{Permalink}")]
    public ActionResult GetExistingStoreBranchesForSelectedHO(string permalink)
    {
         return View("ExistingStoreBranches");
    }
}
```

I am trying to call this action from View using @html.action

```
@Html.Action("Settings/Stores/ExistingStores/{Permalink}",new{permalink=Somevalue})
```

Can't make it work in anyway.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This One worked for me. Still not sure how to use Attribute routing instead of directly calling controller action. Better way is appriciable
`@Html.Action("GetExistingStoreBranchesForSelectedHO", new { Controller = "SettingsMallStores", Action = "GetExistingStoreBranchesForSelectedHO" })`